# symbolic link not working with chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-client

I want to create symbolic link only if its not present

I have written below recipe

```
link '/home/user1/veera' do
    to '/usr/local/veera-10.0'
    only_if {test -L /home/user1/veera}
end
```

I tried below condition in recipe

```
only_if {test -L /home/user1/veera}
```

But it updates the symlink next time when chef runs next time(if it its changed).But i don't want that.

I want to skip this if symlink exist and create only when symlink it doesn't exists.

Also tried this

```
link '/home/user1/veera' do
    to '/usr/local/veera-10.0'
    not_if { File.symlink?('/home/user1/veera') }
end
```

But its still updating the symlink when changed on next chef run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/link/) is idempotent in nature, and shouldn't change if the link is already present.

However, for some reason if you want to skip the step, we can use `symlink?` method from Ruby's [File class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-symlink-3F). This method returns `true/false` based on whether the target path is a link or not.

Like:

```rb
File.symlink?('/home/user1/veera')
```

Another potential issue that I noticed, and corrected in the below example is your source path - `usr/local/veera-10.0` will most likely be relative to your current working directory. To be sure, use `/usr/local/veera-10.0`.

So in recipe:

```rb
link '/home/user1/veera' do
  to '/usr/local/veera-10.0'
  not_if { File.symlink?('/home/user1/veera') }
end
```

*Update*

As @lamont suggested in his comment, try using the `File.exist?` test as you want to skip the step if this path exists (whether its a file, dir, or symlink).

```
not_if { File.exist?('/home/user1/veera') }
```

Comment: I tried this but it updates the symlink next time it runs (if symlink was modified by user).My requirement is not to update symlink if it exists when next time chef runs.It should run this inly when symlink doesnot exists

Comment: In my test, it is skipping the task. Even `test -L /home/user1/veera` can be used but the guard should be `not_if`. Also, in your example, you have `usr/local/...`, which is not exactly `/usr/local/...`

Comment: if i use ```not_if test -L /home/user1/veera ``` it doesnt create symlink if it doesn't exists

Comment: Check by correcting your source path to `/usr/...` and using `File.symlink?`

Comment: I did typo in my question i am giving correct ```/usr/local/veera-10.0```

Comment: Can you update the question with what is changing in the source path? Or I suspect that `/home/user1/veera` is changing from link to directory or file.

Comment: I updated question. Also i verified using ```ls -l``` its not changed to file or directory its l in beginning which means its symlink

Comment: Do you want `not_if { File.exist?('/home/user1/veera') }`?

Comment: That's a good point, though I have a feeling that OP is trying to link directories.